# Как создать функцию для добавления нового объекта в массив

Tags: javascript

Создать массив «Список покупок». Каждый элемент массива является объектом, который содержит название продукта, необходимое количество и куплен или нет. Написать несколько функций для работы с таким массивом.

1. Вывод всего списка на экран таким образом, чтобы сначала шли некупленные продукты, а потом – купленные.
2. Добавление покупки в список. Учтите, что при добавлении покупки с уже существующим в списке продуктом, необходимо увеличивать количество в существующей покупке, а не добавлять новую.

В коде я сделал что бы массив сортировался по статусу( куплена вещь или нет). Далее я в ручную создал новый обьект и добавил его с помощью метода push в массив. Не понимаю, как можно создать функцию которая будет создавать новый обьект этого класса и добавлять его в массив

```js
class Product {
  constructor(nameOfProduct, amount, status) {
    this.nameOfProduct = nameOfProduct;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.status = status;
  }

  static sortProduct(a) {
    if (a.status == 'Не куплен') return -1; 
    if (a.status == 'Куплен') return 1; 
  }

  static showProduct(a) {
    return a.nameOfProduct;
  }
}
 
let shopList = [
  new Product('Банан', 2, 'Не куплен'),
  new Product('Апельсин', 5,'Куплен'),
  new Product('Молоко', 1, 'Куплен'),
  new Product('Груша', 10, 'Не куплен'),
];

shopList.sort(Product.sortProduct);
console.log(shopList.map(Product.showProduct));
let newProduct = new Product('Шоколад', 2, 'Не куплен');

shopList.push(newProduct);
shopList.sort(Product.sortProduct);
console.log(shopList.map(Product.showProduct));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
class Product {
  constructor(params = {}) {
    Object.assign(this, {
      pName: null, 
      amount: 1, 
      bought: false
    }, { ...params }); 
  }

  static sortDefault(a, b) {  // чтобы сначала шли некупленные продукты, а потом – купленные
    return (a.bought - b.bought) * 10 + a.pName.localeCompare(b.pName); 
  }; 
}
Product.prototype.toString = function () {
  return `${this.pName} (x${this.amount}), ${this.bought ? 'куплено' : 'не куплено'}`;
}; 


const shopList = [
  { pName: 'Банан', amount: 2 },
  { pName: 'Апельсин', amount: 5, bought: true },
  { pName: 'Молоко', bought: true },
  { pName: 'Груша', amount: 10 }
].map(prodDef => new Product(prodDef));

const addToShopList = prodDef => {  // при добавлении покупки с уже существующим в списке продуктом, необходимо увеличивать количество в существующей покупке, а не добавлять новую
  const prod = shopList.find(prod => prod.pName === prodDef.pName); 
  if (!prod) return shopList.push(new Product(prodDef)); 
  prod.amount += prodDef.amount; 
}; 
const printShopList = () => shopList.forEach(
  (prod, i) => console.log(`${i + 1}. ${prod}`)
); 

shopList.sort(Product.sortDefault);
printShopList();
console.log('---'); 

addToShopList({ pName: 'Банан', amount: 3 });
addToShopList({ pName: 'Шоколад', amount: 2 });
shopList.sort(Product.sortDefault);
printShopList();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class Product {

  ...

  static addProduct(products, nameOfProduct, amount, status) {
    products.push(new Product(nameOfProduct, amount, status));
  } 
}

...
Product.addProduct(shopList, 'Шоколад', 2, 'Не куплен');
```

---

Посмотрите, как должна выглядеть функция сравнения для `Array.sort`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort